# Register_taxonomy category panel instead of tag panel

Tags: wordpress

Hi I am trying to create a new post type and while registering the taxonomyes I noticed that I get a tag panel instead of the category panel.Here is my code:

```
function portfolio_filter(){
        register_taxonomy("filter", 
                           array("portfolio"),
                           array(
                               "hierarchical => true",
                               "label" => "Filter",
                               "singular_label" => "Filter",
                               "rewrite" => array(
                                   'slug' => 'filter',
                                   'hierarchical' => true
                               )
                           ));
    }
    add_action('init' ,'portfolio_filter' , 0);

  How can I get the category panel instead of the tag panel?
```

Answer (score 1):

I run into the same issue and The WP Codex states that "By default tag labels are used for non-hierarchical types and category labels for hierarchical ones."

Here is how I register my custom taxonomy:

```
add_action( 'init', 'create_product_taxonomy', 0 );

function create_product_taxonomy() {
    register_taxonomy(
                'xyz_products','product',
        array(
                'labels' => array(
                'name' => 'Product Type',
                'add_new_item' => 'Add New Product Type',
                'new_item_name' => "New Product Type Group"
            ),
            'show_ui' => true,
            'show_tagcloud' => false,
            'hierarchical' => true
        )
    );
}
```

..you see the hierarchical is set to TRUE, same as yours but it may not take an effect until you go to your WP dashboard -> Setting -> general (or any other) and click update. That's when the functions.php will reload. (the functions.php file reloads in many instances but this one solved the same issue as you have). Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

You have error in your code:

```
"hierarchical => true"
```

must be

```
"hierarchical" => "true"
```